# compress function in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to remove multiple blanks from a string.

```
%let CDate = 25Mar2015;

data _null_;
call symput('TitleDate',cat(put("&CDate."d,monname9.),', ',year("&CDate."d)));
run;

%put &TitleDate; /* March, 2015 */
%put Title is &TitleDate; /* multiple blanks between 'is' and 'March' */
```

I tried `compress`: `%put Title is %sysfunc(compress(&TitleDate));` But it returns `Title is March` without year part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close, two modifications:

1. CALL SYMPUTX instead of CALL SYMPUT
2. WORDDATE20. format instead of the cat/put combinations

   ```
   call symputx('TitleDate',put("&CDate."d,worddate20.));
   ```

EDIT (to answer question in comments):
The compress function takes 3 arguments, the first is mandatory and the last two are option.

The compress function doesn't work because what SAS is seeing is:

compress(March 25, 2015) 
This is an invalid call to the compress function. I think the compress function would assume the second argument would be 2015 and I don't know what it does with the 25. I would actually expect it to generate an error, but it doesn't.

If you did want to use the compress function to pass in a character value you would need to quote it using the %quote function, but that gets rid of all the spaces and I think you just wanted to get rid of the leading spaces.

```
%put Title is %sysfunc(compress(%quote(&TitleDate.)));
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you explain why `compress` returns truncated result?

Comment: Hi. If you apply only compress function to the macro variable value "March, 2015", then because of ',' SAS will try to compress the string 'March' by '2015' which would result in March.